# How to get a date in milliseconds with moment.js

Tags: datetime, momentjs, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to get a date in milliseconds with moment.js. The problem is, in their docs in unix timestamp section they have only unix timestampt to momentjs format. How can I get a unix timestamp in milliseconds from date?
Eg: `moment.unix(2010-01-01T05:06:07) => 1262318767000`

Answer (score 6):

You can get the date in milliseconds also with `format()`.

`moment("2010-01-01T05:06:07").format('x');`

Comment: It is returning milliseconds from current datetime NOT 2010-01-01T05:06:07

Comment: Strange that it does not work for you. I tried moment('2019-01-19 12:35 PM').format('x') IST and it gives me 1547881500000 which is the UTC. IST = GMT + 05:30

Answer (score 2):

You said that *"in their docs in unix timestamp section they have only unix timestampt to momentjs format"*, but that's not true.

According to https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/:

> `moment#valueOf` simply outputs the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch

So, use the `valueOf` method:

```
moment("2010-01-01T05:06:07").valueOf();
```

But in my machine it returns 1262329567000. That's because moment.js is using my browser's timezone - this milliseconds value corresponds to January 1st 2010, at 05:06:07 AM in my browser's timezone.

The value you mention in your question (1262318767000) corresponds to January 1st 2010, at 05:06:07 AM in a timezone where the offset +01:00 is used: in some place that is one hour ahead of UTC, in January 1st 2010: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets#UTC+01:00,_A

If you want to be specific about what timezone the date/time corresponds to, you can use moment timezone: https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score 1):

`valueOf` function https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

```
console.log(moment('12/09/2021').valueOf());
```

In above example, you will not if it is 12 September or  09 January. It is better to provide the format, which format you're sending the value.

Checkout the below example,

```
moment(dateValue, dateFormat).valueOf();
```

So here we provide the date format which we are sending to moment and again converting it to a format moment understands and then taking out the milliseconds from 1 January 1970. If your date is less than that date, the value will be negative

Example:

```
console.log(moment('09/12/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY').valueOf());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
moment( date ).toDate().getTime();
```

And if you like to use timezone

```
let timezone = moment.tz.guess() || 'America/Los_Angeles';
moment( date, timezone ).toDate().getTime();
```